# Gwt communicates with Spring Rest Api and AutoBean

Tags: json, rest, gwt

I have a standalone Spring Rest Api. I have models annotated with JPA.
I want to write a gwt client using this rest api. 
But, I don't want to create JavaScript Overlay types for each model object type.
The interface logic on Gwt AutoBean looks good but I could not figure out how I integrate with my standalone spring application. Can you help me?
Or do you recommend any other structures to ease the process of handling rest api responses?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to use `AutoBean` together with Spring REST API.
The serialized form of the `AutoBean` mirrors the interface declaration (see [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/AutoBean#JSON_structures) for more details).
I am using `AutoBean` with Spring MVC REST API + Jackson serialzier and it works without any problems (at list for simple beans).

Spring MVC Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET,value="/REST/{id}/data")
public @ResponseBody
    MyDTO getData(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        MyDTO data = null;
        // retrieve data
    return data;
}
```

GWT client side:
AutoBeanFactory:

```
public interface MyFactory extends AutoBeanFactory {
    AutoBean<MyDtoAutobean> data();
}
```

Retrieve AutoBean:

```
MyDtoAutoBean data = AutoBeanCodex.decode(factory,MyDtoAutoBean.class,responseText).as();
```

`responseText` is the body of your GET request to your REST API.

`MyDTO` is a class on the server side and `MyDtoAutoBean` is the corresponding interface on the client (GWT) side. 
They don't have to be the same. However the getters should match otherwise you have to use `@PropertyName`to change the mappping.